# Disable Tab indexing with Ext.grid.Panel in Ext Js 4.0.7

Tags: extjs4

How to disable the traversal through the grid cells when I clicks on the TAB key..ie; is there  any way in extjs to avoid tab indexing..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this,

selType: 'cellmodel',
   selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CellModel',{
      enableKeyNav: false // to disable cell traversal when clicks on keys(es: TAB)
 })

**Just include these lines to your gridpanel (I used cell model for selection)**